# LINQ sum and groupby and return empty records?

Tags: linq

Hi I have a linq query below that groups purchases by month and sums for that month. The query works but when there are no purchases for a given month I want it to return 0 for that month. At the minute it just skps that month. For example if there are only purchases in six months the linq query only returns 6 records i want to to return 12 where 6 would equal 0.

```
                    var purchaseData  = (from p in db.Purchases 
                                where p.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
                                group p by new {p.DateBought.Value.Month} into g
                                select new {g.Key.Month, Sum = g.Sum(p => p.Price)}).ToArray();

            string[] myArray = new string[12];

            for (int i = 0; i < purchaseData.Length; i++)
            {
                myArray[i] = purchaseData[i].Sum.ToString();
            }
```

How would I do this??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create your months

```
var months = Enumerable.Range(1,12);
```

---

Left Join to your purchaseData and you can directly put the results in your array

```
  string[] myArray = (from month in months 
                      from p in purchaseData.Where(x => month == x.Month).DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select p == null ? "0" : p.Sum.ToString()).ToArray()
```